# Увеличение ширины формы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как можно увеличить ширину `select` формы? Прописывал `inline` стили, но не сработало.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <section>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <form action="/get_data" method="POST" class="form-inline">
            <select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker sel" multiple data-live-search="true" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option value= "val">val</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Select</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('select').selectpicker();
        </script>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант (думаю, что не очень хороший, но быстрый) можно поменять стиль этого select'a в стилях bootstrap, либо сделать !important стиль для него. Пример:

```
.bootstrap-select:not([class*="col-"]):not([class*="form-control"]):not(.input-group-btn) {
  width: 600px !important;
 }
```

Comment: вроде работает. Спасибо! а как можно сам выпадающий список из него тоже увеличить или уменьшить, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Аналогично, найдите стандартный стиль в бутстрапе и измените его на нужный, или же опять через !important сделайте.

Comment: можете подсказать пожалуйста как изменить текст `placeholder`? Там стоит `nothing select`, его сменить можно как-то?

Comment: Смените текст nothing select на любой другой

Comment: так его же нельзя сменить, он не прописан в коде